# FosRestBundle trouble with a get route

Tags: php, symfony, fosrestbundle

I have a problem whith FosRestBundle, I had defined the following route :

```
 /**
 * @Get("/resetpassword/{mail}", requirements={"mail"=".+"})
 * @param $mail
 *
 * @return Response
 */
public function getResetPasswordUserAction($mail)
```

The thing is that my $mail variable contain "/resetpassword/myemail@gmail.com", do you know why that take the route path in the var ?

```
fos_rest:
param_fetcher_listener: true
body_listener: true
format_listener: true
view:
    view_response_listener: 'force'
    formats:
        xml: true
        json : true
    templating_formats:
        html: true
    force_redirects:
        html: true
    failed_validation: HTTP_BAD_REQUEST
    default_engine: twig
routing_loader:
    default_format: json
    include_format: false
```

Thank you,

EDIT

I have found the issue, I have an other method that get the user for sended email :

```
 /**
 * @Get("/{mail}", requirements={"mail"=".+"})
 * @param $mail
 *
 * @return Response
 */
public function getUserAction($mail)
```

So my when I was trying to reach my reset password action, the get user action was called and off course with a part off the url path. But I still not understand why that was passing trough my other function but with the first one parameters.

Anyway I have remove the requirement part and now it's works fine, so if you have the same problem be carreful of requirements who act strange.

Comment: Checked your action and it returns email for me, probably the problem in your configuration.

Comment: I have a basic config : `fos_rest:
    param_fetcher_listener: true
    body_listener: true
    format_listener: true
    view:
        view_response_listener: 'force'
        formats:
            xml: true
            json : true
        templating_formats:
            html: true
        force_redirects:
            html: true
        failed_validation: HTTP_BAD_REQUEST
        default_engine: twig
    routing_loader:
        default_format: json
        include_format: false`

Comment: Thanks @ArtemZhuravlev but I have found the issue, look the "EDIT" part. It's the requirement  param that cause trouble.